Geotools GML 3.2 Parsing to Geometry - does geotools suport all GML3.2 types?
currently I'm trying to parse a couple of GML3.2 data to Geometry.
Example 1:
<gml:Ring xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          xmlns:wfs-te="http://www.opengis.net/wfs-te/1.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
          xmlns:wfad="http://axl.avitech.aero/wfsAdmin/1.0" xmlns:sqm="http://axl.avitech.aero/aviWfsSqm/1.0"
          xmlns:smil20lang="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language" xmlns:smil20="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/"
          xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
          xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss"
          xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx"
          xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
          xmlns:fes-te="http://www.opengis.net/fes-te/1.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
          xmlns:dummy="http://dummy.com/dummy" xmlns:axlmeta="http://axl.avitech.aero/schemas/axlmeta"
          xmlns:aixmmsg="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/message" xmlns:aixm="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1">
<gml:curveMember xlink:type="simple">
    <gml:Curve gml:id="id17647">
        <gml:segments>
            <gml:CircleByCenterPoint interpolation="circularArcCenterPointWithRadius" numArc="1">
                <gml:pos>52.60166666666667 -32.919999999999995</gml:pos>
                <gml:radius uom="[nmi_i]">11.0</gml:radius>
            </gml:CircleByCenterPoint>
        </gml:segments>
    </gml:Curve>
</gml:curveMember>
</gml:Ring>

Example 2:
<gml:Ring xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml/3.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
          xmlns:wfs-te="http://www.opengis.net/wfs-te/1.0" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs/2.0"
          xmlns:wfad="http://axl.avitech.aero/wfsAdmin/1.0" xmlns:sqm="http://axl.avitech.aero/aviWfsSqm/1.0"
          xmlns:smil20lang="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/Language" xmlns:smil20="http://www.w3.org/2001/SMIL20/"
          xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
          xmlns:gts="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gts" xmlns:gss="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gss"
          xmlns:gsr="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gsr" xmlns:gmx="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmx"
          xmlns:gmd="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gmd" xmlns:gco="http://www.isotc211.org/2005/gco"
          xmlns:fes-te="http://www.opengis.net/fes-te/1.0" xmlns:fes="http://www.opengis.net/fes/2.0"
          xmlns:dummy="http://dummy.com/dummy" xmlns:axlmeta="http://axl.avitech.aero/schemas/axlmeta"
          xmlns:aixmmsg="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1/message" xmlns:aixm="http://www.aixm.aero/schema/5.1">
    <gml:curveMember xlink:type="simple">
        <gml:Curve gml:id="id17647">
            <gml:segments>
                <gml:GeodesicString>
                    <gml:posList>47.4 -41.6 47.45384232494095 -41.49475160936019 47.507587336034945 -41.389288333791846 47.56123465591919 -41.28360971835344 47.61478390603749 -41.17771531001795 47.66823470664122 -41.07160465771256 47.72158667679048 -40.96527731235865 47.774839434355215 -40.85873282691222 47.827992596016486 -40.751970756404575 47.8810457772679 -40.644990657983485 47.93399859241693 -40.53779209095458 47.98685065458652 -40.43037461682318 48.03960157571668 -40.322737799336444 48.092250966566205 -40.21488120452591 48.14479843671447 -40.106804400750356 48.19724359456332 -39.99850695873905 48.24958604733906 -39.88998845163533 48.30182540109455 -39.78124845504057 48.353961260711415 -39.67228654705846 48.40599322990225 -39.563102308339744 48.45792091121308 -39.45369532212715 48.509743906025776 -39.34406517430085 48.56146181456067 -39.23421145342419 48.61307423587926 -39.12413375078974 48.664580767886925 -39.01383166046581 48.715981007335934 -38.90330477934326 48.767274549828294 -38.792552707182615 48.81846098981899 -38.68157504666165 48.86953992061912 -38.57037140342325 48.920510934399246 -38.45894138612364 48.97137362219286 -38.34728460648098 49.02212757389982 -38.23540067932431 49.07277237829018 -38.12328922264282 49.12330762300779 -38.01094985763554 49.17373289457428 -37.8983822087613 49.22404777839308 -37.78558590378909 49.27425185875347 -37.67256057384874 49.32434471883489 -37.55930585348196 49.374325940711245 -37.44582138069373 49.424195105355444 -37.33210679700403 49.47395179264396 -37.21816174749987 49.52359558136158 -37.103985880887755 49.57312604920629 -36.98957884954638 49.622542772794155 -36.874940309579756 49.671845327664535 -36.76006992087058 49.721033288285305 -36.64496734713401 49.770106228058125 -36.52963225597177 49.819063719324085 -36.41406431892649 49.86790533336919 -36.298263211536515 49.9166306404302 -36.182228613390905 49.965239209700556 -36.065960208184826 50.01373060933631 -35.94945768377528 50.062104406462375 -35.832720732237064 50.110360167178825 -35.71574904991913 50.15849745656729 -35.598542337501215 50.2065158386976 -35.48110030005075 50.25441487663447 -35.36342264708014 50.30219413244438 -35.2455090926043 50.3498531672026 -35.12735935519847 50.39739154100035 -35.008973158056385 50.444808812952104 -34.890350229048664 50.492104541203005 -34.77149030078155 50.5392782829365 -34.652393110655865 50.586329594382114 -34.53305840092631 50.63325803082326 -34.413485918761005 50.680063146605434 -34.29367541630127 50.72674449514424 -34.173626650721744 50.77330162893392 -34.05333938429069 50.81973409955575 -33.93281338443062 50.86604145768678 -33.8120484237791 50.91222325310859 -33.6910442802499 50.95827903471638 -33.569800737094255 51.004208350527975 -33.44831758296253 51.05001074769331 -33.326594611965916 51.09568577250368 -33.20463162373854 51.14123297040161 -33.0824284234997 51.186651885990415 -32.95998482211628 51.23194206304433 -32.83730063616548 51.277103044518526 -32.71437568799767 51.3221343725595 -32.59120980579946 51.367035588515435 -32.46780282365696 51.41180623294689 -32.344154581619236 51.45644584563755 -32.22026492576195 51.50095396560524 -32.09613370825113 51.54533013111303 -31.971760787407153 51.589573879680565 -31.847146027768858 51.63368474809549 -31.72228930015781 51.67766227242523 -31.59719048174273 51.721505988028696 -31.471849456104042 51.76521542956835 -31.346266113298544 51.808790131022405 -31.220440349924218 51.85222962569715 -31.09437206918514 51.8955334462395 -30.96806118095649 51.93870112464975 -30.84150760184969 51.98173219229441 -30.7147112552776 52.02462617991936 -30.58767207151979 52.06738261766305 -30.460389987787917 52.11000103506997 -30.332864948291146 52.15248096110429 -30.205096904301627 52.19482192416363 -30.077085814219984 52.23702345209308 -29.948831643640943 52.27908507220185 -29.82033436541126 52.321006311267816 -29.691593959725534 52.36278669556666 -29.562610414146814 52.40442575087698 -29.433383723702036 52.44592300249762 -29.3039138909402 52.48727797526267 -29.174200925997965 52.52849019355688 -29.044244846665194 52.5695591813311 -28.91404567845041 52.610484462117945 -28.783603454646318 52.651265559047694 -28.65291821639514 52.69190199486429 -28.521990012753967 52.73239329194163 -28.390818900759925 52.772738972299955 -28.259404945495397 52.81293855762252 -28.127748220152966 52.85299156927237 -27.995848806100348 52.89289752830936 -27.863706792945187 52.932655955507315 -27.731322278599677 52.97226637137147 -27.59869536934501 53.011728296156015 -27.46582617989572 53.05104124988186 -27.33271483346383 53.090204752354616 -27.199361461822757 53.12921832318271 -27.065766205371066 53.168081481795745 -26.93192921319601 53.20679374746309 -26.79785064313682 53.24535463931244 -26.663530661847737 53.283763676348954 -26.528969444860838 53.322020377474175 -26.394167176648583 53.36012426150543 -26.25912405068602 53.398074847195254 -26.12384026951278 53.43587165325112 -25.988316044794722 53.4735141983553 -25.852551597385265 53.511002001184856 -25.716547157386373 53.54833458043196 -25.5803029642092 53.585511454824314 -25.44381926663437 53.62253214314575 -25.307096322871914 53.65939616425702 -25.170134400620718 53.696103037116856 -25.032933777127717 53.73265228080311 -24.89549473924649 53.769043414534124 -24.757817583495584 53.80527595769029 -24.619902616116274 53.84134942983582 -24.481750153129905 53.87726335074059 -24.34336052039477 53.913017240402304 -24.204734053662445 53.948610619068795 -24.06587109863366 53.98404300726045 -23.926772011013593 54.019313925792865 -23.78743715656669 54.05442289579969 -23.647866911170894 54.089369438755625 -23.50806166087126 54.12415307649958 -23.368021801933086 54.15877333125809 -23.227747740894305 54.19322972566877 -23.087239894617397 54.22752178280409 -22.946498690340576 54.261649026195194 -22.805524565728348 54.29561097985598 -22.664317968921402 54.32940716830732 -22.52287935858585 54.36303711660141 -22.381209203961685 54.39650035034637 -22.239307984910656 54.42979639573092 -22.097176191963257 54.462924779549255 -21.954814326365096 54.49588502922611 -21.812222900122446 54.52867667284198 -21.669402436046983 54.56129923915839 -21.52635346779982 54.59375225764349 -21.383076539934635 54.626035258497694 -21.239572207940018 54.658147772679506 -21.095841038280955 54.69008933193147 -20.951883608439474 54.72185946880631 -20.80770050695437 54.7534577166932 -20.663292333460095 54.78488360984412 -20.51865969872466 54.816136683400494 -20.373803224686686 54.8472164734198 -20.228723544491462 54.87812251690245 -20.083421302526027 54.90885435181869 -19.93789715445336 54.939411517135795 -19.792151767245507 54.96979355284519 -19.64618581921565 55.0 -19.5</gml:posList>
                </gml:GeodesicString>
            </gml:segments>
        </gml:Curve>
    </gml:curveMember>
</gml:Ring>

        var input = ""//GML3.2 input

        final GMLConfiguration configuration = new GMLConfiguration(true);
        final GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(), 0);
        configuration.setGeometryFactory(geometryFactory);
        final Parser parser = new Parser(configuration);
        parser.setStrict(false);
        parser.setValidating(false);
        Object geometry = parser.parse(new StringReader(input));
        return (Geometry) geometry;

I get the following exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.String cannot be cast to class org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry (java.lang.String is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry is in unnamed module of loader 'app')

From my investigation the current version of geotools 30.2 doesn't support both
CircleByCenterPoint and GeodesicString.
Do I need to extend the org.geotools.gml3.v3_2.GMLConfiguration and write my own bindings ?
Also is there a way to find all of the unsupported  GML3.2 types ?

Yes, it looks like you'll need to add some code. The key bit is how to convert the geometries into something JTS (which is the underlying geometry engine) will understand. I would start by looking at the Oracle and PostGIS code that does handle curved geometries.
